# A power series from $\frac{x}{9+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I need to make power series from $\frac{x}{9+x^2}$, and I don't have any idea how.
The only thing I know is how to make power series from $\frac{1}{1-q}$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac x{9+x^2}=\frac x{9\left(1+\frac{x^2}9\right)}=\frac x9\left(1+\frac{x^2}9\right)^{-1} $$

now apply [Maclaurin series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) and take care of the radius of convergence which demands $\displaystyle \left|\frac{x^2}9\right|<1$

Comment: Thank you! But what I'm doing with the $\frac{x}{9}$?

Comment: @YoavFridman, just multiply with the power series of $$\left(1+\frac{x^2}9\right)^{-1} $$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{x}{9+x^2}=\frac{x}{x^2(1+\frac{9}{x^2})}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{3}{x})^2}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(-\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)^2\right)^j$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\frac{x}{9+x^2}&=\frac12\ln'(9+x^2)=\frac12\ln'\left[9\left(1+\frac{x^2}9\right)\right]=\frac12\left[\ln9+\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}9\right)\right]'=\\&=\frac12\ln'\left(1+\frac{x^2}9\right)\end{align}$$ Now use the fact that $\displaystyle\ln(1-t)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^n}n$ , and replace *t* with $-x^2$, then derive with respect to *x*